# Date not showing up when user submits form

Tags: php

So I have a form that users fill out and it adds to a database. Everything works except for the date. The date shows up as 0000-00-00. Currently, I'm using a datepicker, but the date wasn't showing up even when the user had to type it in...so that shouldn't be the issue.

```
<form name="Add" id="Add" method="post" action="programadd.php">
  <p>Program Name: 
    <input name="program" type="text" id="program" />
</p>
  <p>Air Date 
    <input name="airdate" type="text" id="airdate" />
</p>
  <p>Description 
    <input name="description" type="text" id="description" s />
</p>
<p>Production
    <input name="production" type="text" id="production" />
</p>
<p>Promotions
    <input name="promotion" type="text" id="promotion"  />
</p>
<p>Community
    <input name="community" type="text" id="community" />
</p>
<p>Web
    <input name="web" type="text" id="web"  />
</p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

And here's the code that adds it to the database:

```
<?php require_once('connect-db.php');
$program = $_POST['program'];
$airdate = $_POST['airdate'];
$description =  $_POST['description'];
$production = $_POST['production'];
$promotion = $_POST['promotion'];
$community = $_POST['community'];
$web = $_POST['web'];


if (mysql_query ("INSERT INTO calendar(program, airdate, description, production, community, promotion, web) VALUES 
    ('$program', '$airdate', '$description','$production', '$promotion', '$community', '$web')"))
{ echo "Program successfully added to the database <br />"; 
 }
else {
    die(mysql_error());
}
    require_once("db_connx_close.php");
?>
```

One other question, how do I get the date to display as Month/Date/Year, instead of the reverse?

Comment: try `<input name="airdate" type="date" id="airdate" />`

Comment: what is the date format u are passing from form ? mysql needs dates in Y-m-d format

Comment: you should probably use PDO and prepared statements instead of the pure `mysql_query`.

Comment: Thanks meda, that worked. Martin, can you explain why I should use PDO and prepared statements? Just so I understand for in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['airdate']));
```